# How to enable a hyperlink of a jsp page when clicked on a button on different jsp using struts

Tags: jsp, struts2

My code:

link is in `image.jsp` file

```
<li><a href="error.jsp" target="middle.jsp" disabled="true" name="res">Results</a></li>
```

I have another jsp file called `ballot.jsp`:

```
<form action="ballot">
<input type="button" name="Confirm" value="Result announcement" onclick="AskAndSubmit1(this)"/>
</form>
```

and the action is linked to a java class.

I need to enable the link of `image.jsp` in this java class.
How do i do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not so much clear.. where is the java class all the three are jsps

Comment: I have only two jsp- image.jsp and ballot.jsp..ballot.java is an action class of ballot.jsp...i need to access link in image.jsp and enable it in action class

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Don't disable the link in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following variable in session in your action class when you want to enable the button.

```
session setAttribute("buttonenabled","true");
```

and write in image.jsp following:

```
<li><a href="error.jsp" target="middle.jsp" disabled="<%=session.getAttribute("buttonenabled")!=null ? "true": "false" %>" name="res">Results</a></li>
```

Comment: The boolean compare will already be `true` or `false`, you don't need to also have the strings `"true"` and `"false"` (they're redundant).

Comment: but won't the session expire after a while...so i thought of using a file to write the value

Comment: Ok ..so you want to enable/disable the link at runtime ..But you can also use databse for it rather than considering a file first.